# Issue in using structure in different functions of different classes

Tags: c++

In IHello.hpp file

`#include "trees.hpp"`  // EDITED this line

```
namespace world  
{  
    class IHello  
    {   
      public:     
            struct hi    
            {  
                char a;  
            };  
            void func(plants a);  //// EDITED this line 
    };  
}
```

In Hello.hpp file

```
#include "IHello.hpp"
```

```
class Hello : public world::IHello  
{  
    private:  
            void new_world(hi *init); // function in which struct is used  
            hi init; // initialization of structure , in this file it does not give error  
};
```

In trees.hpp // different file where I want to use the structure

```
#include "IHello.hpp"
```

enum plants
{

```
cactus = 0x01
```

}

```
class trees  
{  
    public:  
           void new_func(hi *b); // using that structure here, shows error of hi structure has not been declared
           // 2nd method - void new_func(world::IHello::hi *b) // error that world has not been declared and 2nd error - error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
};
```

So what do I need to do in order to get the structure which is initialized in class IHello to be visible in class which does not inherit IHello?

Comment: Please put together a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Instead of telling us you've included a file, show us in the code.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I edited that. Is there anything else? This is my first question so still learning the way questions are posted

Comment: @galaxy2096 the true beauty of the [mre] is it's actually a powerful debugging technique. Sure we ask for them to make our jobs easier and chase off the folk who really aren't all that serious about using Stack Overflow to its full potential, But the biggest reason is it's hard to make a MRE without spotting and fixing the error yourself. But if you re still stuck after making the MRE, there will be no ambiguity and someone will pick the problem off and tell you what little trick you're missing to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in class `Hello` because it inherits class `world::IHello`.  The structure `hi` is part of that class, and because it's not a private declaration, it is visible to and usable by `Hello` too.

The error in class `trees` is because this class does *not* inherit `world::IHello` and there is no type named `hi` within the naming scope of where that member function is declared.  That type only exists within the class `world::IHello`.

To fix the error, you must qualify the name so that the compiler knows what you want:

```
void new_func(world::IHello::hi *b);
```

Comment: I have already tried this solution. You can checkout my 2nd method in my question. That has a different error

Comment: In that case, you likely have a circular dependency in your headers.  When you include `IHello.hpp`, something along the way tries to include `trees.hpp` again.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have edited the code again. I understand there was a circular dependency because I need enum value from trees.hpp file in IHello.hpp, so I included trees.hpp in IHello.hpp file. What should I do so that I can see the enum from tress.hpp in IHello.hpp without including trees.hpp file in IHello.hpp

Comment: Change your design.  Normally, you can get away with forward-declaring your class, but since it's a class that lives inside another class, you can't do that.  Now you have two headers that are co-dependent, but only for small pieces of eachother.  When you reach that point, ask yourself how you got there.  Usually that will point you at a fundamental flaw in either the design or how you are organizing its pieces.  Or both.